# jQuery doesn't add class in Drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using `OnePageScroll.js` for my Drupal website but somehow the Javascript file isn't doing anything. Everything is perfectly imported, even the .js file. I put an alert box in it and it works but somehow he doesn't do the rest.

Link to [OnePageScroll.js](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html#)

```
<section class="page1">
        <div class="page_container">
          <h1>One Page Scroll</h1>
        </div>
      </section>
 <section class="page2">
            <div class="page_container">
              <h1>One Page Scroll2</h1>
            </div>
</section>
```

When I open it in a simple `.html` file then I have result but when I upload it to my server to my Drupal website then it doesn't do anything. I noticed the JS file doesn't add the extra class to certain divs..

edit: 
The jQuery files I added:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have not linket the jQuery files correctly. Plain alert works even if you do not have jQuery linked because it is plain javascript. Try to alert the following in order to find out:

```
alert($("div:first").text());
```

Comment: Okay, so it's jQuery because it does work on a simple .html file but not when upload it to my Drupal site.. Any idea what the problem could be? They both import jQuery in the <head> from an extern location.

Comment: Can you post the jquery link scripts in your post? I am interested about the source part

Comment: I've added them to my post

Comment: They seem good. Could be about cross origin policy on your server. Can you copy paste those jquery codes to the server and link them from there?